Movie with alien ship in the desert, similar to Arrival (2016)
I saw a film in the 00's that is very similar to Arrival (2016).

Somewhere in the desert is an alien spaceship that looks like a rock (looks like a funnel).
A scientist goes there, and they try to figure out how to open its door. They find nine holes that represent the solar system's planets. They figure out the combination, and get inside the ship. After that, one of them enter into a fully white room (very bright) where she communicates with the aliens.


Welcome to the community. If you know, please also describe the movie’s language, country and year of production, plot locale, names of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Epoch
Detailed plot:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(film)
Here is a poster where you can see the funnel like spaceship/monolith:

You can watch the complete movie (dubbed in Hungarian) here:



The scene where the soldier is in the white room inside the alien ship starts ca. at the 0:48:18 mark.
There is a sequel to this movie, titled Epoch: Evolution:

