# What is this movie? Very similar to Arrival

Tags: identify-this-movie

About 10 years ago I saw a movie which I can't find any information about. I have lost the name of the title so I will try to explain what it's all about.

There was most likely a woman in a team that was going to explore an unknown structure that looked like a black mountain that was smaller on the bottom than on the top. In some way it can be described as a non symmetrical pyramid that was upside down. I have memories of the team exploring the structure from the inside and it reminded me a lot of the new movie Arrival.

Anyone has any idea of what this movie is called?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Any other plot details? If you know, please also describe the language, country and year of production, descriptions of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Comment: [Related?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63322/movie-with-alien-ship-in-the-desert-similar-to-arrival-2016/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Epoch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0233657/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

[Detailed plot On Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(film))

Here is the non-symmetrical pyramid spaceship/monolith:

[image]

You can watch the complete movie (dubbed in Hungarian) here:

There is a sequel to this movie, titled [Epoch: Evolution.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0374286/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

Comment: Wow there it is! Thank you so much! I wonder if it's just me who see the similarity to Arrival.